# OpenCV--program stop running @ the step of detecting image key-points

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to develop a c++ implementation of bag of visual word using the `opencv` library

I started by testing keypoints detection function but when I insert this instruction

`detector->detect(img, keypoints);`, the program stop running @ the first image without throwing any exception.

Can any one help me how to fix this problem ?

Thanks

```
void extractTrainingVocabulary(const path& basepath) {
for (directory_iterator iter = directory_iterator(basepath); iter
        != directory_iterator(); iter++) {
    directory_entry entry = *iter;

    if (is_directory(entry.path())) {

        cout << "Processing directory " << entry.path().string() << endl;
        extractTrainingVocabulary(entry.path());

    } else {

        path entryPath = entry.path();
        if (entryPath.extension() == ".jpg") {

            cout << "Processing file " << entryPath.string() << endl;

            Mat img = imread(entryPath.string());
            if (!img.empty())
            {

                cout << "not empty"<< endl;


                try{
                    // ...
                    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                    cout << "not empty"<< keypoints.empty()<<endl;
                    //detector->detect(img, keypoints);
                } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
                }



            }
            else
            {
                cout << " empty"<< endl;

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume that the detector->detect() function in that code is actually not commented out in your implementation. My only guess would be that the img.empty() function is not returning the correct value. The OpenCV method of checking to see if an image loaded correctly is using the image.data data member, as such:

```
if(! image.data )  // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
```